# Stripping spaces (%20) from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I remove spaces (`%20`'s) from the following code?

```
var newTab = {"url": config.searchEngines[newTabIndex].url.replace(new RegExp("%s", "g"), info.selectionText).replace(new RegExp("%S", "g"), info.selectionText)}
```

`selectionText` is a phone number that is highlighted on a web page. Obviously adding `20` to the number causes the number to become incorrect.

Comment: You may actually be wanting to pass your string through [`window.decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: @PaulS. Passing it to `decodeURI` is probably more appropriate since it seems  to be a full URL.

Comment: I am afraid I would not know how to implement this. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `decodeURIComponent()` Function
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

```
var uri = config.searchEngines[newTabIndex].url,
    newTab = {"url": decodeURIComponent(uri)};
```

Comment: Documentation is on MDN [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) and in the ES5 spec [**here**](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.3.2)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I did initially look at this but my JS skills are v poor, I need some expert help in context :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove spaces instead of replacing with `%20`, unless they are part of a string or after `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
str=str.replace(/%20/g,"")
```

so for your code

```
var newTab = {"url": config.searchEngines[newTabIndex].url.replace("%20", ""), info.selectionText).replace(/%20/g,""), info.selectionText)}
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your code suggestion as my JS is non existent. On testing this it is apparent that the **replace(new RegExp("%s", "g")** and **replace(new RegExp("%S", "g")** parts are still required as it causes a malfunction. Please could you suggest how it might be possible to add to the existing code with your suggestion rather than replace parts of it.